# Автоматический выход из аккаунта. Django

Tags: python, django

Как можно сделать автоматический выход из аккаунта по истечению определенного времени? Вроде бы была возможность "из коробки" но я уже забыл что нужно прописать в файле настроек.

Comment: [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое